# Spring Redirect to another url in web.xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on API java project using Spring, and I want to redirect a specific url to another specific url. I know this is possible to achieve using the controller, however I'd like to know if this is possible just configuring the web.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**, this is not achievable through simple *XML* configuration.